# How can I make new QGIS projects use absolute path by default?

Tags: qgis, file-path

New QGIS projects are saved with relative path location for data sources by default.

If you want to use absolute path, each time a new project is created, this setting needs to be changed in the project properties dialog box.

How can I make absolute path the default behavior for new projects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Options | General, there is a setting to **Create new project from default project**. You can create a default project that uses absolute paths and tell QGIS to use that as a template for all new projects.